# csv file changes numers to exponential not being recognized

Tags: database, csv, exponential

I have a software that exports certain amount of data from a database to *.csv files. These files are to be exported to another entity, that will import these *.csv files onto their system.
thing is, for some reason, the numers on these files are being converted to exponential, example:

```
5600026136414 is showing as 5,6E+12 and recognized on the other side as 5600030000000, and since 5600026136414 is my individual reference 5600030000000 is pointing to another person.
```

is there a way where, in the csv file, i can save the values as they originally are, without the exponential?

Comment: refer to this: https://superuser.com/questions/1083454/editing-csv-file-in-excel-always-converts-number-column-to-scientific-notation

Comment: if your opening in excel then change the column datatype from number to text.

Comment: @Sucharitha that´s exactly what i was searching, thank you very much!!